# Installing SQL Server 2017 through the Configuration File (.ini)

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, sql-server-2017

I am trying to install SQL server 2017 through the CMD line, but I keep getting the same error (attached below).

My steps are

1. Downloaded the SQL Server 2017 ISO
2. Generated the .ini file, by going the installing wizard and stopping when I get the file directory.
3. Run the CMD line from the location of the sertup.exe file
4. Passing the parameters with the .ini file (attached)

CMD line

```
E:\setup.exe /ConfigurationFile=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200423_134227\ConfigurationFile.ini/SQLSVCPASSWORD=asdfasdf /AGTSVCPASSWORD=seqsdf /SAPWD=dfasdf /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

Configuration File (.ini)

```
;SQL Server 2017 Configuration File
[OPTIONS]
IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS="True"
ACTION="Install"
SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE="False"
IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS="True"
ENU="True"
QUIET="True"
QUIETSIMPLE="False"
UIMODE="Normal"
UpdateEnabled="True"
USEMICROSOFTUPDATE="False"
UpdateSource="MU"
FEATURES=SQLENGINE
HELP="False"
INDICATEPROGRESS="False"
X86="False"
INSTANCENAME="MSSQLSERVER2017"
INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server"
INSTANCEID="MSSQLSERVER2017"
SQLTELSVCACCT="NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$MSSQLSERVER2017"
SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\SQLAgent$MSSQLSERVER2017"
AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
COMMFABRICPORT="0"
COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL="0"
COMMFABRICENCRYPTION="0"
MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT="0"
SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
FILESTREAMLEVEL="0"
ENABLERANU="False"
SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER2017"
SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT="False"
SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="user"
SECURITYMODE="SQL"
SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT="8"
SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE="8"
SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH="64"
SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE="8"
SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH="64"
ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="False"
TCPENABLED="0"
NPENABLED="0"
BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled"
```

**Error:**

[image: Error Screen Shot]

Comment: Could be that there is space missing between ConfigurationFile.ini and /SQLSVCPASSWORD ? Also, maybe you need to enclose your path between " ".

Comment: like this: E:\setup.exe /ConfigurationFile="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200423_134227\ConfigurationFile.ini" /SQLSVCPASSWORD=asdfasdf /AGTSVCPASSWORD=seqsdf /SAPWD=dfasdf /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS